# How to avoid copy and paste when two functions are very similar?

Tags: c++, dry

I often come across methods that have the same structure and logic, but with some differences and I don't find a proper way not to repeat myself.

For example :

```cpp
void ChannelSelection::selectAlmostOkChannels(int currentInkId)
{
    bool selected = true;
    foreach (auto report, m_reports) {
        if (report.scoreByInk.find(currentInkId) != report.scoreByInk.end()) {
            auto tmpStatus = Assessment::getStatusFromScore(report.scoreByInk.value(currentInkId));
            if (tmpStatus == Assessment::Ok)
                selected = false;
            else if (tmpStatus == Assessment::NotOk)
                m_autoSelection[report.name].setSelected(currentInkId, false);
        }
    }
    m_currentSelection.insert(currentInkId, selected);
}

void ChannelSelection::selectNotOkChannels(int currentInkId)
{
    bool selected = true;
    foreach (auto report, m_reports) {
        if (report.scoreByInk.find(currentInkId) != report.scoreByInk.end()) {
            auto tmpStatus = Assessment::getStatusFromScore(report.scoreByInk.value(currentInkId));
            if (tmpStatus == Assessment::Ok || tmpStatus == Assessment::AlmostOk)
                selected = false;
        }
    }
    m_currentSelection.insert(currentInkId, selected);
}
```

As you can see, these 2 functions are very similar (only the inner if differs). How could I nicely remove duplication in this code?

One of the solution I thought of is using a functor, something like :

```cpp
void ChannelSelection::selectChannels(int currentInkId, std::function<bool()> fn)
{
    bool selected = true;
    foreach (auto report, m_reports) {
        if (report.scoreByInk.find(currentInkId) != report.scoreByInk.end()) {
            auto tmpStatus = Assessment::getStatusFromScore(report.scoreByInk.value(currentInkId));
            selected = fn();
        }
    }
    m_currentSelection.insert(currentInkId, selected);
}
```

The caller gets the responsibility to implement the functor. Is there an alternative without that problem?

Comment: This question seems to be more suited to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since it seems that this question is primarily-opinion based, since it is based on preferences.

Comment: Not a c++ guy, but aren't templates the thing you're looking for?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hum, unless I'm missing something, I'm not sure to see how templates could help here.

Comment: @R0m1. Total stab in the dark. I'm really not a c++ guy :)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, I disagree - it's a "how can I" question, not a "should I" one.

Comment: @TobySpeight It's "_Does that sound reasonable?_" question. And the "reasonability" is dependent on opinion, in my opinion.

Comment: @Algirdas: I was placing more weight on the question title, but I see now why we disagree.  If we changed the last sentence to, "Is there an alternative without that problem?", would that make it on-topic?

Comment: @TobySpeight I guess so. It would have prevented me immediately jumping to thinking "opinion-based", at the very least. It was unclear what "that problem" is, in such a question, but then thought that it might have referred to "_The caller gets the responsibility to implement the functor._"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to make your parameterized `selectChannels` public. It can be a private implementation detail of both `selectAlmostOkChannels` and `selectNotOkChannels`, your public functions.

`selectChannels` can even be implemented as a function template, so that the generated code is equivalent to the hand-written "copy pasted" version, without the maintenance burden of code duplication

```
template<typename SelectFunction>
void ChannelSelection::selectChannels(int currentInkId, SelectFunction selectFn)
{
    bool selected = true;
    foreach (auto report, m_reports) {
        if (report.scoreByInk.find(currentInkId) != report.scoreByInk.end()) {
            auto tmpStatus = Assessment::getStatusFromScore(report.scoreByInk.value(currentInkId));
            selected = selectFn(tmpStatus);
            /* fill in */
        }
    }
    m_currentSelection.insert(currentInkId, selected);
}

void ChannelSelection::selectAlmostOkChannels(int currentInkId)
{
    selectChannels(currentInkId, [] (auto tmpStatus) -> bool {
        return /* fill in */;
    });
}

void ChannelSelection::selectNotOkChannels(int currentInkId)
{
    selectChannels(currentInkId, [] (auto tmpStatus) -> bool {
        return /* fill in */;
    });
}
```

You might have been taught that templates need to be in headers, but that's actually not the full story! Template definitions need to be *visible where instantiated*. Since your template is only used in the private implementation of your member functions, then your template definition can be in the same file that's implementing both your member functions

Comment: Nice solution, because the day I need to add another selectChannelStuff method, I won't have  to modify the existing code!

Answer (score 1):

You might merge two functions into a single one with additional conditional parameter like:

```
void ChannelSelection::selectChannels(int currentInkId, bool condition)
{
  bool selected = true;
  foreach (auto report, m_reports) {
    if (report.scoreByInk.find(currentInkId) != report.scoreByInk.end()) {
      auto tmpStatus = Assessment::getStatusFromScore(report.scoreByInk.value(currentInkId));
      if (condition) {
        if (tmpStatus == Assessment::Ok) {
          selected = false;
        } else if (tmpStatus == Assessment::NotOk) {
          m_autoSelection[report.name].setSelected(currentInkId, false);
        }
      } else if (tmpStatus == Assessment::Ok || tmpStatus == Assessment::AlmostOk) {
        selected = false;
      }
    }
  }
  m_currentSelection.insert(currentInkId, selected);
}
```

Calling it with `condition == true` will invoke the equivalent of `selectAlmostOkChannels()` function, and `selectNotOkChannels()` otherwise.

Comment: Easy to implement, but the downside is it won't scale easilly :)

Comment: The given implementation is for the demonstration only. However you should think on why are you forced to write such a code (with the complex conditioning). I believe it can still be simplified, but I cannot tell more without knowing the rest of the project.